# How to sort list of two paired elements by their weight?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm dealing with such problem:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    elem1 = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    elem2 = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    ziplist = list(zip(values,weights))
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, elem1, elem2)
```

So, as I typing

```
3 40
20 40
50 60
70 80
```

I got such list

```
[(20, 40), (50, 60), (70, 80)]
```

I need to sort my list by the value of "weight", where weight is

```
elem1/elem2
```

While testing, I made such list

```
m = list(x/y for x,y in ziplist)     
[0.5, 0.8333333333333334, 0.875]
```

And I see that the last element has the best weight, so I need my initial list sorted like this:

```
[(70, 80), (50, 60), (20, 40)]
```

I was reading about sorting with key, but I can't understand how to write my proper condition, something like that

```
 newlist = ziplist.sort(key=lambda m = x/y for x, y in ziplist m)
```

And moreover, how can I work with my sorted list in order to get elem2 from the first index. So, I have such sorted list:

```
[(70, 80), (50, 60), (20, 40)]
#code implementation 

a = 70 #output
b = 80 #output
```

Comment: `newlist = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0] / x[1], reverse=True)`. If you are using python 2.x, you need to convert int to float to avoid int division (truncate) : `newlist = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: float(x[0]) / x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: `sorted(ziplist, key = lambda x : -x[0] / x[1])`

Comment: `sorted(ziplist, key = lambda x : x[0] / x[1], reverse = True)`

Answer (score 4):

`sorted(l, key=lambda elem: elem[0] / elem[1], reverse=True)`